# Multiple subsection columns in Beamer (warsaw)

Tags: beamer

I've got quite a few subsections in one section and they stretch the right half of the header. Hoping to split them up into 2+ columns.

Minimal example:
[image: example with stretched header and one column]

Some research indicates that this will involve `\setbeamertemplate{headline}` ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123202/69200)) and probably modifying `\insertsubsectionnavigation`, but I don't know enough LaTeX to do this. I'd appreciate a hand!

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\subsection{i}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{ii}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{iii}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{iv}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{v}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{vi}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{vii}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{viii}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are deadset on using the **Warsaw** theme with a default `\useoutertheme{default}`, the answer to your question appears to be [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47939/beamer-with-warsaw-theme-two-column-navigation).

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that before. Unfortunately it [doesn't vertically centre](http://imgur.com/b4RjIAu) (there's more space at the top than the bottom) in either the demo or my real case where it's more pronounced. Wound up using the Hannover theme instead.

Comment: Good information! I did not notice that looking though it. I generally stick with a different theme as well.